# Add a constraint to a nonlinear model in R

Tags: r, nls

I'm having trouble adding a constraint to my nonlinear model. Suppose I have the following data that is roughly an integrated Gaussian:

```
x = 1:100
y = pnorm(x, mean = 50, sd = 15) + rnorm(length(x), mean = 0, sd = 0.03)
model <- nls(y ~ pnorm(x, mean = a, sd = b), start = list(a = 50, b = 15))
```

I can fit the data with `nls`, but I would like to add the constraint that my fit must fit the data exactly (i.e. have no residual) at y = 0.25 (or whatever point is closest to 0.25). I assume that I need to use `glmc` for this, but I can't figure out how to use it.

I know it's not necessarily kosher to make the fit adhere to the data like that, but I'm trying to replicate another person's work and this is what they did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could impose the restriction somewhat manually. That is, for any parameter `b` we can solve for a unique `a` (since the cdf of the normal distribution is strictly increasing) that the restriction would hold:

```
getA <- function(b, x, y)
  optim(x, function(a) (pnorm(x, mean = a, sd = b) - y)^2, method = "BFGS")$par
```

Then, after finding `(tx,ty)`, the observation of interest, with

```
idx <- which.min(abs(y - 0.25))
tx <- x[idx]
ty <- y[idx]
```

we can fit the model with a single parameter:

```
model <- nls(y ~ pnorm(x, mean = getA(b, tx, ty), sd = b), start = list(b = 15))
```

and get that the restriction is satisfied

```
 resid(model)[idx]
# [1] -2.440452e-07
```

and the coefficient `a` is

```
getA(coef(model), tx, ty)
# [1] 51.00536
```

Comment: So for each parameter `b` the constraint means that there is exactly one pnorm line that goes through the proper point. Thus, the constraint effectively reduces the model down to a 1-parameter model. Good observation.

Comment: @Gabe, yes, since the cdf or normal distribution is strictly increasing, we have exactly one solution.